# access mypage.php from /mypage only not /mypage.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-extension

iam creating a php website and iam using htaccess to hide php extensions with this script

```
  Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

so if i access `localhost/mypage.php` or `localhost/mypage` both will redirect me to `mypage.php` 
i want if i accessed it from `/mypage.php` then redirect me to my page not found page 
i mean that the user must access it from `localhost/mypage` only
any ideas ??

Comment: You can certainly force all `*.php` pages to your error document, but why do you want that? It's an inconvenience for your visitors.

Comment: i don't want to show the language i uses !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a 404 error code and force any PHP request to an error document

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule \.php$ - [R=404,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
```

This returns a `404` error code for all `*.php` requests and shows `/error_404.html`. The `RewriteCond` is there to prevent an error code for the already rewritten pages.

Comment: iam speechless MR. @OlafDietsche you made my day with this code :D

Answer (score 0):

have you thought of using a framework like Zend? My suggestions is more complex i know but....

1) the framework will help you a lot on developing.
2) you will be able to set up all type of routes.
3) there will be no .php extensions.
4) the .htaccess will be really easy to maintain, you will use the standard one of the framework.

Thanks.